# How to import jquery-ui properly

Tags: html, jquery-ui, effect

I can't get it to work and can't find any answers. Nothing is working for me.

Am I wrong by writing this into my header?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

my code is right, it's working in jfiddle but not outside of it.

Comment: Are you using it in an HTTP page or a local file?

Comment: add an http: before the //ajax...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you leave the scheme out of a URL, it uses the scheme from the page that contains the URL. So your `<script>` tag should work if the URL for the page is `http:something` or `https:something`; the reason for leaving out the scheme is so that it will use SSL if your page uses SSL, because browsers often complain if a secure page tries to load a non-secure script.

If you're trying to load jQuery from a local file instead of an HTTP page, you need to put the `http:` scheme into the jQuery URL explicitly.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got it working by adding  `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` above the code

Comment: Where are people getting these links???  This is not an answer unless we can find the link when future updates are made to the script.
Today [<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
] does not work.

Comment: @JoshuaRobison The point of the answer is to show the need for the `http:` or `https:` prefix in the URL. The rest of the URI is specific to the API or library being loaded and not relevant to the answer.

Comment: the question is not "How to import a remote javascript library properly?"  The question is "How to import jquery-ui properly" / JQUERY-UI .  If the question were simply about remote javascript library, it would be a duplicate.  Where are the Jquery-ui links?  How do we find them?